# how to define early bound entities?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm attempting to compile [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx) code sample.

It has a dependency on SystemUser:

```
                    // Now make an SDK call with the organization service proxy.
                // Display information about the logged on user.
                Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)organizationProxy.Execute(
                    new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
                SystemUser systemUser = organizationProxy.Retrieve("systemuser", userid,
                    new ColumnSet(new string[] { "firstname", "lastname" })).ToEntity<SystemUser>();
                Console.WriteLine("Logged on user is {0} {1}.",
                    systemUser.FirstName, systemUser.LastName);
```

But SystemUser is an early bound entity, is it not?

**Is there an implementation of SystemUser that I can use? Does Microsoft provide a library?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a tool to generate early bound entities. There are multiple ways to do so:

- The classic way is to use [CrmSvcUtil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx).
- Use the [Early Bound Generator](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/wiki/Early-Bound-Generator) in [XrmToolBox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/). This is basically a user interface for CrmSvcUtil along with various improvements.
- Use [CRM Code Generator for Visual Studio](https://github.com/xairrick/CrmCodeGenerator), which also runs CrmSvcUtil with a few improvements.
- Use [XrmContext](https://github.com/delegateas/XrmContext/wiki), which is a rewritten-from-scratch tool outputting early bound classes similar to the ones generated by CrmSvcUtil with various improvements. *Full disclosure: I work for the company that made this tool (and I would highly recommend using it)*.

Which tool you end up using does not matter so much. It matters more that you actually use one. I find that it is a great benefit over using late bound entities.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the Crm Code Generator for Visual Studio Henrik.  Cool.  I'll add that the Early Bound Generator also allows you to store settings specific to the connection you have, and handles checking things out of TFS, adding them to the project, and adding to TFS.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain "DLaB.Xrm.Entities" a NuGet Package of Early Bound Entities.  It won't contain any customizations that you've done, but it will have the default attributes/entities.

Answer (score 1):

All answers here are fine, but the simplest (and fastest) way to run this code is to use the classes provided in SDK itself in

```
\SDK\SampleCode\CS\HelperCode\MyOrganizationCrmSdkTypes.cs
```

The example project that you are trying to compile is already referencing this classes:
[image]